# Close console while process is running

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, windows-console

I'm writing a small application that uses an "index-file" to open folders in explorer from just a few button presses. Anyway I would like to update that index file in a "background process" every time the applications shuts down. Updating the index file means scanning through our network and for some remote users it could take a few minutes. That's why I would like it to hide the console during the scanning process in order to avoid the process being aborted by user.

I tried several things similar to:

```
#these are just dummy lines
path = get_user_input()
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer "%s"' % path)
#Here I start my update process
multiprocessing.Process(target=update_index).start()
#end of script, now I want that process to continue until finished while main console closes. I only seem to get one or the other.
```

I also tried using:

```
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, 
                 stderr=None, 
                 creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS|CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

and managed to get a separate console window but still no way from preventing the user for closing down the process.

Also keep in mind I would like to distribute this script with something like py2exe later to make it accessible for those without python so I guess using pythonw.exe is out of question. or?

Comment: Should the script normally have a console? If not, use a .pyw file that runs with pythonw.exe.

Comment: BTW, `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` is ignored if you also use `DETACHED_PROCESS` because it makes no sense to combine them. `DETACHED_PROCESS` makes sense for running a console app without a console only if it doesn't spawn child console processes because they'll just create their own console windows. With this flag you should also redirect the standard handles to the `NUL` device. `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` works for child processes because they'll inherit the windowless console. Similarly, you can use `STARTUPINFO` to hide the console window.

Comment: Yes the script normally should have a console, cause in the first part the user i promted two questions to answer. At least thats how it's done right now, a possibility could be to promt those questions in some other kind of window than a console, I will try that when I'm back at the office. Regarding the flags for the subprocess method I don't have much clue how they work I just googled found those and tried different combinations, thanks for letting me in on the details a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

That's not really the answer you're looking for, but you could redesign your system architecture: Write your index updater as a server process that's communicating with your actual application over sockets. Then you just have the index updater server process run continuously (maybe even on another machine) and have the index updater process do all the time-consuming work.

Comment: Like you said not exactly what I'm looking for. Sure it could be an solution but I didn't want to make such a big deal of this script. Setting up such service means quite more work and involving other people on the company that are able to host such service. Compared to just have index file stored on the network that is updated when used.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to perform background tasks that happen at certain intervals, then use `cron`. If you want to run a command in the background and keep it running even if you logout of the console, use `nohup`.

Comment: This question is tagged for Windows, and the OP's code is meant for Windows (e.g. running "explorer" and using `creationflags`).